# Response from fetch() post is incorrect

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I'm quite new to promises, im building a simple app using json placeholder. For some reason my data response is incorrect and i cannot figure out why.

```
console.log(data) // returns {id: 101} It should return {title: 'xx', body: 'xx'
```

I've spent about an hour now googling this issue, do i have a syntax error? or maybe have i miss understood some documentation? Any help would be appreciated, please see my code below.

```
import React from 'react';

class PostForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        body: ''
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
}

onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const post = {
        title: this.state.title,
        body: this.state.body
    };

    // console.log(post) // returns title: 'xxx', body: 'xxx';

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        haders: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data)) // this returns {id: 101} It should return my post object with the inputs from the form fields;
}

render() {
    const { title, body } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Add Post</h1>

            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="title"
                        value={title}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <br />
                    <textarea
                        name="body"
                        value={body}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

```
export default PostForm;
```

any help is much appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: This is the default behavior calling jsonplaceholder.typicode.com service when you don't provide any payload. Try with curl: `curl -X POST https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` instead of `curl --data "aaa=555" -X POST https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

So: your `body` is empty

Comment: i do see one type-o in your request config: `haders` should be `headers` I think

Comment: @Nielsvandenbroeck thanks very much!!! That was the problem. What a silly mistake. I think i may need to get thicker glasses! thanks again.